# How to add/remove uiimage in a uitableviewcell at a specific row

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, ios7

in the below code i am trying to show an image on the selected row and removing the image from the previously selected row. On scrolling the tableview up and down the selected image start to appear on random rows also instead of just showing on the one selected. Can anyone here please help me fix it. I am testing this on ios7 device.
Thanks.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_checkmark_off.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(270, 15, 17, 17);
    imageView.tag = CELL_IMGVIEW_TG;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
}
return cell;
```

}

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
if (self.prevRowIndex != indexPath.row)
{
    NSIndexPath *pPrevIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.prevRowIndex inSection:indexPath.section];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:pPrevIndexPath];
    UIImageView* pImgView = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:CELL_IMGVIEW_TG];
    pImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_checkmark_off.png"];
    // update index
    self.prevRowIndex = indexPath.row;

}
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView* pImgView = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:CELL_IMGVIEW_TG];
pImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_checkmark_on.png"];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 15, 17, 17)];
        imageView.tag = CELL_IMGVIEW_TG;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    }

    UIImageView* pImgView = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:CELL_IMGVIEW_TG];
    if (self.prevRowIndex == indexPath.row) {
        pImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_checkmark_on.png"];
    }
    else{
        pImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_checkmark_off.png"];
    }


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.prevRowIndex = indexPath.row;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And you'd better replace `prevRowIndex` with `selectedRowIndex` which will be clear for understanding.

Comment: In order to remove the previously selected image i believe we need to call [self.tableView reloadData] instead of reloadRowsAtIndexPaths. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this line:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

by

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Every time i scroll the UITableView up or down it creates a new UITableViewCell and if the row was selected its image is switched to off. Is is okay to create a new UITableViewCell instead of using the dequeued one?